# How can I check if a given address is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit, memory-address

How can I check if the address value in a long variable is 32bit or 64bit

Example:

```
long a = 0x06000000
long b = 0x13FFF0000
```

How can I programmatically check the bitness of these addresses?

Comment: A 32-bit address is also a 64-bit address because 0x1 and 0x00000001 are the same number and the same address. Do you mean to check if your process is running in 64-bit mode? Or do you mean to see if a given number fits in a 32-bit register?

Comment: If your app is running as a 32 bit process on Windows, it will not have access to 64 bit memory at all. The WOW64 layer will prevent it.

Comment: @MiguelVentura Second option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an AND operation to check if any of the higher 32 bits are set. Assuming that you have `ulong` because addresses are not negative:

```
if ((x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000UL) == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("x would fit into 32 bit");
```